# TwoWay binding listbox - removing item

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, two-way-binding

I have a `ListBox` (x:Name = `notesList`) in my WPF application which takes items by `ItemsSource` from collection. The collection is a `Notes` property in my class `Data` and is of type `ObservableCollection<Note>`. I bind it this way: (`data` is a `Data` object that have some items in `Notes`)

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
bind.Source = data;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Notes");
notesList.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);
```

The binding works, items are shown in ListBox. I set TwoWay binding, because I want the `notesList` and `Notes` collection to be synchronized. The problem occurs when I try to remove selected item this way:

```
NotesList.Items.RemoveAt( notesList.SelectedIndex );
```

I get exception: "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead".

My question: Do I have to use collection function to remove element? `data.Notes.RemoveAt(index)` ? Is there any way to remove item using `ListBox` class so it will result removing item in collection? I thought that using TwoWay Binding it will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

All that error means is that when you have used the `ItemsSource` property to bind a collection to a collection control, you can't remove items from that control. Don't worry though, there's a *really* simple solution. Remove the item from the collection instead:

```
data.Notes.Remove(data.Notes.Where(n => n == notesList[notesList.SelectedIndex]).
FirstOrDefault());
```

It's better to not use the control in your code behind... if you bind a property to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property, then you can simply do this:

```
public Note SelectedNote { get; set; } // should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
```

... then...

```
data.Notes.Remove(SelectedNote);
```